# 'selectAll' ambiguous: Selection objects with contenteditable false and display block

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

This behaviour is observed in Chrome.
When we have a block element with no text and contentEditable set to false, browser is not able to select the text content.

Whereas the same code snippet works correctly in Firefox

So is this a bug in Chrome or expected behaviour ?

```
 <div id="contentsContainer" contenteditable="true" >
  <div id="contents">
    <div id="section">
      <div>
          <div>
            <div contenteditable="false" id="imgContainer" style="display:block;">
              <span contenteditable="false"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>
          <span>
            Some text
          </span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[Find JsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/xw2zsvh8/)

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: I want to understand whether this is a bug in chrome or is this the expected behaviour

Comment: Does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251227/contenteditable-div-not-actually-editable-in-webkit) help?

Comment: actually no, the question you pointed to talks of user-select cascaded to 'none'. How ever in my case I am able to set the cursor in contentEditable areas. However the behaviour of 'selectAll' is ambiguous, when we have block elements and inline elements